# Seasonal naive in forecast package with multi-step prediction

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am working on predicting a time series of daily data for one month that looks like this:
[image: Time-series daily data]

As can be seen, the time-series has a weekly seasonality. I am trying to predict the next week's data (horizon=7), updating my forecasts every day, so at each time-step, I am getting forecasts for the next 7 time-steps.

I have tried a number of methods but I would expect at least the snaive method to give me something reasonable. The code I am using is (tseries is an XTS object with the daily data):

```
for (t in horizon:(length(a)-horizon)) { # Every day
  timeseries <- ts(a[1:(t+horizon)], frequency=7)
  fit <- snaive(timeseries[1:t], h=horizon)
  plot(forecast(fit, h=horizon))
  lines(1:(t+horizon),timeseries, col='black')
}
```

The method consistently gives me flat predictions, looking like this:
[image: SNaive prediction for the next 7 days]

Has anyone had any similar problems? Is it because I set frequency=7 for my daily data?

Comment: try `fit <- snaive(ts(timeseries[1:t],freq=7), h=horizon)` `snaive()` gives you already a forecast btw, so i don't understand what you are doing in your `plot()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfect. Why is this happening? I am new to R and forecasting and I thought that by doing the ts() would give me a ts object.

Comment: Also not an expert but i think the way how you sliced the ts-object you actually just extracted the values...

Comment: We build daily models quite frequently . Daily data often reflects day-of-the-week effects , auto-regressive effects , level shifts , unusual values , time trends and of course holiday effects both pre and post . Additionally certain days of the month effects and  week-of-the-month effects are often needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer from the comment of RandomDude:

```
fit <- snaive(ts(timeseries[1:t],freq=7), h=horizon)
```

snaive() gives you already a forecast btw

It did not work probably because of the way how the user sliced the ts-object, he actually just extracted the values